# Prefix/Suffix Data Validation List

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm finding it really difficult to understand how to prefix or suffix a set of words based on a what I have chosen in a 'Data Validation List'.

[CLICK HERE TO SEE/DOWNLOAD AN EXAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FUMX_fxi4GTzFDUVlRMkUzams/view?usp=sharing)

I have a list of words in column A and a list of words in column B.

In Cell C1 i have a data validation list and the options are 'Suffix' or 'Prefix'

What i would like to happen in (Column D), is if i choose Suffix to place all words in column B after of all words in column A. And if I choose Prefix to place all words in column B before all words in column A.

*FYI - I'm using Excel 2013 and also there can be any number of words in column A and B.*

I've tried using concatenate formulas but populating a list of words based on what is selected from a data validation list is way beyond my knowledge.

[image: SCREENSHOT OF EXAMPLE SPREADSHEET]

So, In column D, if i chose Suffix then id want all combinations to show like this:

- orange yogurt
- orange ice cream
- orange milkshake
- orange drink
- apple yogurt
- apple ice cream
- apple milkshake
- apple drink
- banana yogurt
- banana ice cream
- banana milkshake
- banana drink

[image: Suffix Example]

In column D, if i chose Prefix then id want all combinations to show like this:

- yogurt orange
- ice cream orange
- milkshake orange
- drink orange
- yogurt apple
- ice cream apple
- milkshake apple
- drink apple
- yogurt banana
- ice cream banana
- milkshake banana
- drink banana

[image: Prefix Example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data as 1/ nobody should have to download a potentially dangerous file from an unknown source and 2/ if the link changes or the file is removed then the question will be missing vital information.

Comment: you don't have to download the spread sheet, i gave it as an option as a screenshot will not show my formulas. The link will not change or get removed unless i do that myself. But i have done as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your response datatoo. I tried that formula before i posted and it worked to a certain extent, but it doesn't give every option I require, it only combines the cells in a row depending on the choice in C1. Maybe i didn't explain the result I'd like well enough. I've extended my original question to show how id like the results to show, with a screenshot.

Comment: Your response to datatoo should be a comment to his answer, then  he will get notified. I'm not sure he will see one posted as a question comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the value of the selected validation choice and in Column D
have a formula such as the following.

```
=IF(C2="Prefix",A2&" "&B2,B2& " "&A2)
```

if you want to make the suffix, prefix choice in a single cell such as C1 alter the formula to something like

```
=IF(C$1="Prefix",A2&" "&B2,B2& " "&A2)
```

Comment: The OP has a comment to you under his question. I don't think you will have been notified about it ...

Comment: I guess the question is other than I understood it. It appears that it would require multiple similar formulas depending upon the content of both A and B. My approach would change if this is the case. Probably using a macro doing the type of same string concatentation depending upon the validation cell would make sense if that is the case. Would that work for you?